# Summon TNT at arrow after hitting object

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am creating a custom PVP map, where all arrows explode after they hit something. For example, if an arrow hits a block or a non-TNT entity, a TNT is summoned at that location. Here is the command I tried:

Repeating command block, always active:

```
/execute @e[type=arrow] ~ ~ ~ summon tnt ~ ~ ~
```

However, when the arrow is shot, TNT spawns wherever the arrow is, creating a disaster. How do I fix this?

**Note:** If an instant-explosion is possible, I prefer that, but if not, that is okay as well.

Comment: In Java Edition you would use the NBT tag `InGround`, but in Bedrock Edition, you'd have to do a little trickery with entities and stuff that I don't know about.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 So do you have any small thoughts about this?

Comment: In Java Edition, if I wanted to do this without NBT access, I would teleport an invisible entity like an  `area_effect_cloud` to the arrow every second or so, and detect when the armour stand's movements are slowing down by calculating its distance to the arrow with every move. I'll have to ponder about this a bit to be able to convert this to Bedrock Edition.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 So if a TNT blows up on top of an arrow (the arrow and and the TNT share space), does the arrow get removed?

Comment: The arrow didn't get removed with the TNT explosion on the first trial run just now. I'm not sure if this is a fluke or not. Which scenario would be better for your purpose, and is multiplayer-compatibility important?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Custom PvP gamemode implies multiplayer is necessary.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Its just a single player test trial. I can port it to multiplayer if I want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bedrock edition, you can not detect if an arrow is in the ground, but you can detect if a certain block is under it. You would use a different repeating command block for every possible block it could land on. If your were on a riverbank, it could land on either grass or sand, so it would look like this:

> [image] **#1:** `execute @e[type=arrow] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ grass 0 summon tnt ~ ~ ~`

> [image] **#2:** `execute @e[type=arrow] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ sand 0 summon tnt ~~~`