# Summoning a ring/sphere of arrows around an arrow which had just struck the ground

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been messing around with bows and arrows and summoning stuff when the arrow hits the ground, like lightning, but I've got an idea I do not really know where to start at.

So here's the plan, I would shoot an arrow, and when it hits the ground, it would summon a sphere/ring of arrows, surrounding the original, and then also strike the original point where the original arrow is hit.

There are 2 things I don't know about this.
First, is there a way to 'set' the direction of an arrow? I know you can do it with a fireball, using:

```
/summon fireball ~ ~1 ~ {direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]})
```

but it will not work on an arrow, so that's one problem.

Second (not much of a problem, but it would be nice to simplify it), how would you summon arrows around the original arrow? When I was watching how to make a circle in vanilla Minecraft (by Mysticat), it summons an armor stand which turns around, summoning stuff as it does, but summoning a whole ring will take approximately 1 second, which is too much.
There *is* kind of a way to get through this, but it requires a bit of manual work, by calculating exactly where to summon the arrow (like, `~ ~-5.67 ~` or something). I think it might work, but if there is a way to simplify this further, let me know.

Finally, there's the arrangement of the command blocks. This is my idea:

```
[REPEAT] Detect arrow, shot from a specific bow, give it a tag (let's say, clonearrow).
```

Another chain:

```
[REPEAT] Detect an arrow which has that tag (clonearrow), and is in the ground
[CHAIN] Summon arrow with position ~(something) ~(something) ~(something)
[CHAIN] Summon arrow with position ~(something) ~(something) ~(something)
[CHAIN] Summon arrow with position ~(something) ~(something) ~(something)
...
[CHAIN] Summon arrow with position ~(something) ~(something) ~(something)
[CHAIN] Kill arrow
```

Is this the optimal arrangement? It might be a bit weird, but it's something I got from my previous questions, by mind overflow.

(The main thing is: can you set the velocity of an arrow? This could fully well be impossible, so if it is impossible, you can tell me.)

Comment: You might find this helpful: [Summon TNT at arrow after hitting object](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/375819/220080)

It's in BE though, but the comments you find there might be helpful. Try using the `InGround` NBT tag

Comment: @fasterthanlight Yep, I already knew how to detect if an arrow is in Ground. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I believe the video in question is about Mysticat, you might want to change your spelling to make it more clear

Comment: @Hacker someone edited it

Comment: Yep, I rejected that edit which was useless, but somebody accepted it anyway....